# How to sort with JMESPath in ansible playbook?

Tags: json, ansible, ansible-facts, jmespath

I have an array returned by curl from consul during playing ansible playbook:

```
[
       { 
        "Node": {
            "Node": "test-eu-west-2-staging-0"
        },  
        "Node": {
            "Node": "test-nyc1-staging-0"
        },
        "Node": {
            "Node": "test-sfo1-staging-0"
        }
       }
]
```

I want to have it sorted by `"Node": {"Node" : "hostname"}` in ansible playbook

```
- name: Set TEST vars, servers info and number
    set_fact:
      TEST_SERVERS="{{ test.json | json_query('SOME SORTING QUERY') }}"
      TEST_SRV_NUM="{{ test.json | length }}"
```

I have read JMESPath and ansible docs for whole day but still don't know how to implement it (btw it is easy in jq `sort_by(.Node.Node)` but this trick is not applicable to ansible)

Comment: The JSON you posted is malformed, to start with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @techraf noted, your sample JSON is malformed. I can make a guess that you have a list of objects with `Node.Node` inside, in this case you can use [sort](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#sort) Jinja2 filter:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    myvar: [
       { "Node": { "Node": "test-c" } },
       { "Node": { "Node": "test-b" } },
       { "Node": { "Node": "test-a" } }
      ]
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ myvar | sort(attribute='Node.Node') }}"
```